# Edit Promoted Result - Render on banner throws error

Tags: search-results, promoted-results

I created a New query rule for our Search Center in SP2016 Enterprise.  The query looks for "Query Contains action Item" in the Query Conditions and I added an action term "acquisitions".

I also added a Promoted Result "WARINING: This Content is Classified as Confidential" with a URL to the Legal Policy.  In the "Edit Promoted Result" dialog Window, I checked "Render the URL as a banner".

The search result throws an error when this is Checked, stating "This content cannot be displayed in a frame"

Could this be a bug?

Bismarck

Screenshots:
[image: Edit Promoted Result Dialog]

[image: Promoted Result with Banner Checked]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display template is attempting to use an iFrame to render the content. It is likely that your ContentPolicies page is not "iFrame-able". (It probably also will look like crap in that tiny frame.)

What I would do is upload an ASPX file to the Search Center documents library that contains a good looking rendering and warning with a link to the ContentPolicies page.

This is one I use in a similar scenario for "Training Content". Save it as an ASPX file and it works great. (I use an image that is 500x140px.)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SharePoint Class</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>SharePoint classes y'all!</h2>
    <p>July 5th, 2017<br/>Austin, TX</p>
    <a href="http://www.criticalpathtraining.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="willa study.jpg" alt="Take the SharePoint Class!" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;z-index:-1;border:none;"/>
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah yes, now I understand what it's trying to do. I like your idea if just using a Hyperlinked Image.  Thanks.